# Exception occur in facebook sample

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Facebook
>   authorize:delegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x684fe80'

```
- (void)loginToFacebook:(id) loginDelegate
{
    NSLog(@"login facebook method");

    fbServiceRequestingobj = loginDelegate;

    NSArray* permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the message is pretty straightforward: the parameter `loginDelegate`, which you set as the delegate, does not respond to the selector. to verify the parameter when you set it:

```
- (void)loginToFacebook:(id)loginDelegate
{
  assert([loginDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(authorize:delegate:)]);
```

chances are good in this scenario, that the selector in question is a `@required` method for the protocol you are expected to adopt. if so, then the parameter you pass as `loginDelegate` would need to implement the method `authorize:delegate:` declared in the protocol.

when adopting a protocol, the compiler can inform you if you do not implement the required methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

Does this method exist for the "facebook" object?  I'd imagine not, as it is crashing saying that this method doesn't exist, hence the "unrecognized selector sent to instance".